# Netbeans - Use correct JRE for debugging on Kubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, netbeans

I know this question has been asked before, but the solutions do not work.

I've installed a new jdk 1.8 and configured it as platform.  In netbeans.conf I've configured  netbeans_jdkhome="/home/niklas/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/".

using update-alternatives I've configured the new jre for java. `java -version` correctly returns "java version "1.8.0_65"

Nevertheless running my project from inside netbeans it does not load, instead the "javafx requires newer version" error appears.

When I run exactly the same project with `java -jar` it runs correctly.

What did I forget to configure?

Comment: Your project is capable of running against different JVMs/JDKs.  Check the project properties.  Under `Libaries`, make sure the `Java Platform` is pointing to `JDK 1.8`, if it's not listed, you might need to click `Manage Platforms` and `Add Platform`.  Once you've satisfied that, check under `Sources` (project properties) and makre source `Source/Binary Format` is also set to JDK 8

Comment: both is already set to correct jdk

Comment: You might consider removing the current version of Netbeans and re-installing it, allowing it to pick up the new installation of the JDK

Answer (score 0):

After long try-and-error here my solution:

the standard ubuntu package seems not to contain javafx. Therefore netbeans has to be installed from netbeans downloadpage.

Step-by-step solution:

- **Uninstall** netbeans (e.g. sudo apt-get remove netbeans)
- **Download** netbeans-8.1-javase-linux.sh
- **Run** `sh netbeans-8.1-javase-linux.sh --javahome /[PATH_TO_JDK]/jdk1.8.0_[VERSION]`   (note that this installer fails without warning if you use [PATH_TO_JDK]/jre/)
- **Edit** [INSTALLATION_DIR]/etc/netbeans.conf
- **Make sure** netbeans_jdkhome="[PATH_TO_JDK]" points to the right path (it didn't in my case.) and has no # before

note that the "All"-linux installer from the downloadpage is broken today (11.11.2015). Maybe this will be fixed soon.